# how to delete node from firebase using html button and javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

This is my current web data:
[image: current output]

I can't call my JavaScript function for delete().
because my button are append in html. my onclick aren't working

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("Feedback").orderByKey();
query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(feedbackSnapshot) {
           var uid = feedbackSnapshot.key;
            feedbackSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var key = childSnapshot.key;
                var TicketNo = childSnapshot.child("feedID").val();
                var Subject = childSnapshot.child("feedSubject").val();
                var Message = childSnapshot.child("feedMessage").val();
                var deleteRef = "Delete(key,uid)";
                            
                $("#feedback_table").append(
                    "<tr><td>"+Message+"</td><td>"+Subject+"</td><td>"+TicketNo
                    +"</td><td><button onclick="+deleteRef+">Remove</button></td><td style='display:none;'>"+uid
                    +"</td><td style='display:none;'>"+key+"</td></tr>");
            });
    });
});
```

this is my delete function :

```
  function Delete(key,uid){
      var feedRef = firebase.database.ref("Feedback").child(uid).child(key);
      feedRef.remove()
      .then(function(){
        console.log("Remove succeeded.")
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log("Remove Failed!"+error.message)
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on this line:

```
var deleteRef = "Delete(key,uid)";
```

So instead of using this please replace it with:

var deleteRef = "Delete("+key+","+uid+")";

It will work for sure because now we are actually providing it the value while providing its reference t o deleteRef variable.

Comment: i tried your code, but the button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ES6 template literals when you append your HTML instead of quotes and reference the function like this.

And btw, functions starting with capital letter usually indicates the function being a class. You should name you functions in lowercase(function Delete(key,uid) should be function delete(key,uid))

```
$("#feedback_table").append(
`<tr><td>${Message}</td><td>${Subject}</td><td>${TicketNo}
</td><td><button onclick="delete(${key}, ${uid} );">Remove</button></td>
<td style='display:none;'> uid </td><td style='display:none;'>${i}</td></tr>`);
```